# Flutter ObjectBox Unit Testing - Failed to load dynamic library 'lib/objectbox.dll'

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I'm building my new Flutter app with objectBox as DB.

When I write a unittest that includes objectBox, at running the test I get following error message:

> Failed to load "C:\Dev\flutter_rebuild\test\db_model_test.dart": Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'lib/objectbox.dll': 126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on:
https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/objectbox-dart
It shows how to download an include the "objectbox.dll" to Windows so that the test can run in Android Studio.

> 2. **Dart standalone programs:**
>
>    - Install the packages pub get
>    - Install objectbox-c system-wide:
>
>      - macOS/Linux: execute the following command (answer Y when it asks about installing to /usr/lib)
>
>        `bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/main/install.sh)`
>
>        - macOS: if dart later complains that it cannot find the libobjectbox.dylib you probably have to unsign the dart binary (source: dart issue):
>
>          `sudo codesign --remove-signature $(which dart)`
>      - Windows: use "Git Bash" or similar to execute the following command
>
>        `bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/main/install.sh)`
>
>        Then copy the downloaded lib/objectbox.dll to C:\Windows\System32\ (requires admin privileges).
>
> ObjectBox generates code binding code for classes you want stored based using build_runner. After you've defined your persisted entities (see below), run `pub run build_runner build` or `flutter pub run build_runner build`.

Comment: found in C:\Users\{User}\lib